# How to make the size of a grid element dynamic in CSS?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I have a question for sizes in CSS. I have a Figma files with a grid, I want to keep the same size of this Figma files.

For example on a 1728px width screen I have these sizes:
the grid is 1708x1487, the 1st div (red) is : 678x1487 / the 2nd div (blue) is : 507x489 / the 3rd div (green) is : 507x489 / the 4th div (indigo) is : 1022x493 and the 5th div (purple) is : 1022x489. Everything is in pixels. The grid got a margin left and right of 10px and each element got a gap of 8px.

And I wish my grid in a 1024px width screen to be 1004x873,
with the 1st div to be : 399x873 / the 2nd div : 297.49x286.93 / the 3rd : 297x287 / the 4th : 602x291 / the 5th to be 602x287. Those data are just from Figma the gap changed and now it's just 4.42. If it keeps it gap of 8px it's still alright.

Here I want to know or understand if there is a calculation so it keep it's those size but depending on the screen size. I don't want to create multiple media queries for the grid. I want to know if there is a way to make those elements in the grid goes from the 1728px width screen to 1024px size. I know I can't find the right terms to.

I use TailwindCSS but I feel like in vanilla CSS it will be more possible. For example the calc() function but I'm not quite sure what to do

I first try a grid with the data that I gave you. but of course when the windows get changed the grid keeps the size and the horizontal scrollbar appears. I try also to create a grid of 2 columns and inside the second columns to use the flexbox to create the grid. That feels like the best solution but the entire size of the grid need to be dynamic I feel like.

I try the calc() function with a calculation to get a vh and vw but I don't know if it's the right way.

[image]

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question and not just state a broad topic.

Comment: Media queries are how to shrink and grow stuff based on browser window size. Could attempt to use `clamp`, but it'd require a bit of trial and error and may not work right anyways.